# Graph API and location privacy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm aware that the Post Graph API object has a privacy attribute that can be specified when an app is allowing the user to create a post.

From that documentation, we can see that:

> The description field may contain a comma-separated lists of valid country, city and language if a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified.

Fantastic. So where do we retrieve the current, valid country, cities and languages that are allowed to be used in that field? Guess work? An FQL table that isn't in the docs?

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question:

A little un-intuitively, perhaps, you can grab this information from the Facebook ads api [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/)